# displaydefaultdatetime error after generating jhipster entity from microservice

Tags: microservices, jhipster, gateway

I have an error after generating entity from a microservice as follows:

```
date-utils has no expected member displaydefaultdatetime
```

So how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it in the file! In file **src/main/webapp/app/shared/util/date-utils.ts** add this:

```
    export const displayDefaultDateTime = () =>
  moment()
    .startOf('day')
    .format(APP_LOCAL_DATETIME_FORMAT);
```

And run the following command again:

```
$ npm start
```

OR

```
$ yarn start
```